# On the existence and uniqueness of solutions of non-linear differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Are there theorems that could be applied to show the existence/uniqueness of solution of such system :

$$
(S) \left \{ \begin{aligned}
 p''&= f_1(b) \\
 q'' &= f_2(x,p,q,b)\\
 q~~ &= f_3(x,p,b) 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

where $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are non linear functions ? and $p$, $b$ and $q$ are real and positive functions defined on a compact $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R+}$ ?

Comment: Is the last line of $(S)$ supposed to be $q=...$?

Comment: Yes why ? it characterizes how q is a function of the other unknowns $p$ and $b$.

Comment: If or where the last equation can be solved for $b$ this is an index-1 DAE in semi-explicit form. The general theory of differential-algebraic equations applies, which gives here apart from said solvability no further restrictions.